# Запись видео со всего экрана или только с окна приложения

Tags: c#, видео

Подскажите библиотеки, которые позволяют через C# записывать видео со всего экрана, а также записывать только определенное окно приложения. Желательно оптимизированные.

Comment: Гуглить пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net

Comment: @AntonKomyshan ссылки на тот вопрос не находил. Сейчас оформлю в качестве переведенного ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оригинальная тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net)

---

Одним из лучших решений для этого, возможно, будет Windows Media Encoder.

Немного ссылок, правда на английском:
[На c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/armoghanasif/CaptureDesktopActivities11122005013755AM/CaptureDesktopActivities.aspx)
[На codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CaptureScreenAsVideo.aspx)
[На mycomponent.blogspot.com](http://mycomponent.blogspot.com/2009/04/capture-screen-activitiesvideo-using.html)

---

Код, приведенный ниже использует SharpAvi доступный на NuGet.

**Заметка**: Демонстрация только базового функционала. Посмотрите [здесь (Captura)](http://github.com/MathewSachin/Captura) для более детального описания, такого как захват кликов и нажатия клавиш, FFMpeg поддержку, итд.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharpAvi;
using SharpAvi.Codecs;
using SharpAvi.Output;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Captura
{
// Used to Configure the Recorder
public class RecorderParams
{
        public RecorderParams(string filename, int FrameRate, FourCC Encoder, int Quality)
    {
        FileName = filename;
        FramesPerSecond = FrameRate;
        Codec = Encoder;
        this.Quality = Quality;

        Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    }

    string FileName;
    public int FramesPerSecond, Quality;
    FourCC Codec;

    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public AviWriter CreateAviWriter()
    {
        return new AviWriter(FileName)
        {
            FramesPerSecond = FramesPerSecond,
            EmitIndex1 = true,
        };
    }

    public IAviVideoStream CreateVideoStream(AviWriter writer)
    {
        // Select encoder type based on FOURCC of codec
        if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed)
            return writer.AddUncompressedVideoStream(Width, Height);
        else if (Codec == KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg)
            return writer.AddMotionJpegVideoStream(Width, Height, Quality);
        else
        {
            return writer.AddMpeg4VideoStream(Width, Height, (double)writer.FramesPerSecond,
                // It seems that all tested MPEG-4 VfW codecs ignore the quality affecting parameters passed through VfW API
                // They only respect the settings from their own configuration dialogs, and Mpeg4VideoEncoder currently has no support for this
                quality: Quality,
                codec: Codec,
                // Most of VfW codecs expect single-threaded use, so we wrap this encoder to special wrapper
                // Thus all calls to the encoder (including its instantiation) will be invoked on a single thread although encoding (and writing) is performed asynchronously
                forceSingleThreadedAccess: true);
        }
    }
}

public class Recorder : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields
    AviWriter writer;
    RecorderParams Params;
    IAviVideoStream videoStream;
    Thread screenThread;
    ManualResetEvent stopThread = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    #endregion

    public Recorder(RecorderParams Params)
    {
        this.Params = Params;

        // Create AVI writer and specify FPS
        writer = Params.CreateAviWriter();

        // Create video stream
        videoStream = Params.CreateVideoStream(writer);
        // Set only name. Other properties were when creating stream, 
        // either explicitly by arguments or implicitly by the encoder used
        videoStream.Name = "Captura";

        screenThread = new Thread(RecordScreen)
        {
            Name = typeof(Recorder).Name + ".RecordScreen",
            IsBackground = true
        };

        screenThread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        stopThread.Set();
        screenThread.Join();

        // Close writer: the remaining data is written to a file and file is closed
        writer.Close();

        stopThread.Dispose();
    }

    void RecordScreen()
    {
        var frameInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / (double)writer.FramesPerSecond);
        var buffer = new byte[Params.Width * Params.Height * 4];
        Task videoWriteTask = null;
        var timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;

        while (!stopThread.WaitOne(timeTillNextFrame))
        {
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

            Screenshot(buffer);

            // Wait for the previous frame is written
            videoWriteTask?.Wait();

            // Start asynchronous (encoding and) writing of the new frame
            videoWriteTask = videoStream.WriteFrameAsync(true, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            timeTillNextFrame = timestamp + frameInterval - DateTime.Now;
            if (timeTillNextFrame < TimeSpan.Zero)
                timeTillNextFrame = TimeSpan.Zero;
        }

        // Wait for the last frame is written
        videoWriteTask?.Wait();
    }

    public void Screenshot(byte[] Buffer)
    {
        using (var BMP = new Bitmap(Params.Width, Params.Height))
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BMP))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, new Size(Params.Width, Params.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                g.Flush();

                var bits = BMP.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Params.Width, Params.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
                Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                BMP.UnlockBits(bits);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

***Примеры использования***
Создайте консольное приложение
Add Reference to `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms`. (Использования `System.Windows.Forms` можно избежать, если вы измените код).
Установите SharpAvi из NuGet.

```
using Captura;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Using MotionJpeg as Avi encoder,
        // output to 'out.avi' at 10 Frames per second, 70% quality
        var rec = new Recorder(new RecorderParams("out.avi", 10, SharpAvi.KnownFourCCs.Codecs.MotionJpeg, 70));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Stop...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Finish Writing
        rec.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```